# Are SF comics considered for the same awards as books?

Tags: comics, awards

Are SF comics considered for the same awards as books?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What SF book/film awards are there?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/478/what-sf-book-film-awards-are-there)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not generally, no. The Hugo awards have a separate award for "graphic stories", and the Nebulas don't have any comic categories at all. I'm not aware of any award, in any genre, where comics and novels compete against each other for the same award.

One notable exception: [In 1991, Neil Gaiman and Charles Vess won the World Fantasy Award in the "Short Fiction" category for *Sandman*'s "A Midsummer Night's Dream."](http://www.worldfantasy.org/awards/1991.html) Even there, though, comic books now compete in the "Special Award" category, rather than competing with prose fiction (the [official rules](http://www.worldfantasy.org/awards/judges.html) state *"We never made a change in the rules"*, which sits oddly with the *Sandman* win). At any rate, this case seems like the exception that proves the rule.