# Is there a website that shows which SF book/film awards there are?

Tags: online-resources, awards

What website references the SF awards that are awarded to science fiction books and films?

Comment: Is the question restricted to English works only?

Comment: @DVK no restriction; I'd be interested in any awards for any SF work in any language.

Comment: OK, added another source tracking both English, foreign, and Russian specific ones.

Comment: Closing as a list question.

Comment: See the [ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/should-this-list-question-really-have-been-closed/).

Comment: @Gilles - is there a policy about Mods helping re-open the question that the community clearly (3 reopen votes) feels deserves to be reopened if there were only 2 close votes? If not, I'll ask on meta - I feel such a policy is warranted

Comment: @DVK Yes, mods can help reopen question, when something has changed after the votes to close. Indeed, you are encouraged to flag a question if you edited it after it was closed and think this makes it a good question for the site. All this is subsumed by a meta discussion; we'll follow the results of the discussion (still ongoing as I write).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a [website](http://www.sfawardswatch.com/) devoted to tracking and reporting on SF awards, so I suggest you start there. The awards they currently list are:

```
Aeon Award
Andre Norton Award
Arthur C. Clarke Award
Aurealis Awards
Australian Shadows Awards
Big Heart Award
Bram Stoker Awards
British Fantasy Awards
British Science Fiction Association Awards
Carl Brandon Awards
Chesley Awards
Compton Crook Award
Constellation Awards
Cordwainer Smith Rediscovery Award
Damon Knight Memorial Grand Master
Darrell Awards
David Gemmell Awards
Deutscher Phantastik Preis
Deutscher Science Fiction Preis
Ditmar Awards
Endeavour Award
ESFS Awards
First Fandom Hall of Fame Award
Forry Award
Fountain Award
Gaylactic Spectrum Awards
Geffen Awards
Golden Duck Awards
Grand Prix de l’Imaginaire
Helsinki Science Fiction Society Awards
Hugo Awards
International Horror Guild Awards
Jack Gaughan Award
James Tiptree, Jr. Award
James White Award
John W. Campbell Award for Best New Writer
John W. Campbell Memorial Award
Komatsu Sakyo Award
Lambda Literary Awards
Le Prix Européen Utopiales des Pays de la Loire
Locus Awards
Lord Ruthven Awards
Mythopoeic Awards
Nebula Awards
Nihon SF Taisho Award
Philip K. Dick Award
Premi Ictineu
Premio Italia
Premios Ignotus
Prix Aurora Awards
Prix Imaginales
Prometheus Awards
Quill Book Awards
Rhysling Awards
Robert A. Heinlein Award
Saturn Awards
Science Fiction Hall of Fame
Scribe Awards
Seiun Awards
Shirley Jackson Awards
Sidewise Awards
Sir Julius Vogel Awards
Sky Awards
Skylark Award
Southeastern Science Fiction Achievement Awards
Southern Fandom Confederation Awards
Spectrum Awards (Art)
Sunburst Awards
Theodore Sturgeon Memorial Award
Ursa Major Awards
William L. Crawford Fantasy Award
World Fantasy Awards
Worldcon Special Awards
WSFA Small Press Award
```

Comment: I +1'd all the responses that included the Israeli Geffen award, but it seems that even those sites are missing the second Israeli SF award that's given out annually. I'll nudge the award committee to get the word out. :)

Answer (score 9):

Locus tracks just about every SF Award ever given at [The Locus Index to Science Fiction Awards](http://www.locusmag.com/SFAwards/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

The Hugo and Nebula awards are the most notable awards for Sci-fi literature. The Hugo has been given out since 1955 and the Nebula has been given out since 1965.
The Arthur C. Clarke Award is also given out annually, since 2005

[Hugo Awards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_awards), [Nebula Awards.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula_awards), [Arthur C. Clarke Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke_Award)

The Saturn Award is a notable award for Sci-fi films, and has been awarded since 1972.

[Saturn award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Award_for_Best_Science_Fiction_Film)

Comment: I think you mean the Arthur C Clarke Award, the Sir Arthur Clarke Award is for "notable contributions to space exploration."

Comment: @Amos you're correct

Answer (score 3):

This page tracks awards in Russian, both English ones, global ones (they have some Polish, German and Spanish at only a single glance) and Russian specific ones.

http://fantlab.ru/awards

These are the non-Russian specific ones (English and global):

They have not simply the list of awards, but for many (if not all) recent winners.

```
AnLab award (Analog)
Arthur C. Clarke Award
Asimov
Balrog Awards
BaltCon
Black Quill Award
Bram Stoker Awards
British Fantasy Award
British Science Fiction Award
Crawford Award
David Gemmel Award
Deutscher Phantastik Preis
Deutscher Science Fiction Preis
EuroCon (ESFS Awards)
Hall of Fame
Hans Christian Andersen Award
Hugo Award
International Fantasy Award
International Horror Guild Awards
James Tiptree Jr. Award
John W. Campbell Memorial Award
Locus Award
Lord Ruthven Award
Mythopoeic Awards
Nagroda "SFinks"
Nagroda Literacka im. Jerzego &#379;u&#322;awskiego
Nagroda Nautilus
Nagroda im. Janusza A. Zajdla
Nebula Award
PEN/Saul Bellow Award
Philip K. Dick Award
Premios Nocte
Prometheus Awards
Robert A. Heinlein Award
SFRA Awards
Shirley Jackson Award
Sidewise Awards
Skylark
The Astrid Lindgren Memorial Award
The Booker Prize
The Cordwainer Smith Rediscovery Award
Theodore Sturgeon Award
World Fantasy Award
World Horror Convention Grand Master Award
```

And here are Russian only ones:

```
 Аэлита
 Великое Кольцо
 Беляевская премия

 Странник
 Мечи
 Фанкон

 АБС-премия
 Бронзовая Улитка
 Сигма-Ф

 Интерпресскон
 РосКон
 Звёздный Мост

 Портал
 Зиланткон
 Полдень

 Премия Кира Булычёва
 Русская фантастика
 Лунная радуга

 Бронзовый Икар
 Созвездие Аю-Даг
 Заветная мечта

 Басткон
 Филигрань
 Русский Букер

 Большая Книга
 Серебряная стрела
 Мраморный фавн

 Астрея
 Рваная грелка
 Меч без имени

 Мир фантастики
 Премия им. Тита Ливия
 Премия имени Александра Грина

 Книга года по версии Фантлаба
 ФантЛабораторная работа
 Независимая литературная премия «Дебют»

 Антипремия "Гриадный крокодил"
 Национальный бестселлер
```