# Are there reference sci-fi websites that maintain lists of "must have" books?

Tags: books, online-resources

Are there websites that maintain lists of "must have" English SF books?

As an example, in French, there is [La Bibliothèque Idéale de l’Imaginaire](http://www.cafardcosmique.com/La-Bibliotheque-Ideale-de-l)  from *Le Cafard Cosmique*, which loosely translates to *The Ideal Library of the Imagination*.

Comment: This almost seems like the same question as [What SF book/film awards are there?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/478/what-sf-book-film-awards-are-there), asked a couple of hours ago, only phrased differently.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard No, some good S-F books don't won any award, example: I don't think the "Culture series" from Iain Banks won any major award. A good list include the books that where overlooked when they where published, but are now recognized as "masterpieces".

Comment: Those are good points.  I guess some gems do get passed over even for nominations.

Comment: @Bill: A good list would include classics that predate awards. @DavRob60: there are several different notions of “must have”: most influential? most enjoyable? most philosophically profound? … Any particular notion in mind?

Comment: @Gilles No, I just found the french link I put in the question useful and I was wondering if there was any equivalent in English.

Comment: can we start a community wiki of must read sci-fi novels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well these are these two websites. This site, [The Classics of Science Fiction](http://classics.jameswallaceharris.com/ByRank.php) has got a pretty good list, based on a citations metric, i.e. the number of times they are mentioned in blogs, sites, email, across the web. Some books I've not read. Worth a look.

The second subsite, found [162 Classics of Science Fiction 1996](http://classics.jameswallaceharris.com/Lists/SFClassics1996.html) is also based on citations as well. The second list is much more detailed. The citations detailed, are if they have been mentioned in the reference works at the top of the article.

Answer (score 7):

The lists of [Hugo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Award_for_Best_Novel) and [Nebula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula_Award_for_Best_Novel) nominees would probably be the best places to start.

Answer (score 2):

Another list can be found at [Scifi Lists](http://home.austarnet.com.au/petersykes/topscifi/lists_books_rank1.html). There are actually 200 books listed as well as short stories, movies and TV shows.

Answer (score 1):

Another good site is http://greatsfandf.com/, which despite its dated look was last updated June of 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There was a list that was maintained since beginning of the nineties by Tristrom Cooke. Unfortunately, the list hasn't been maintained since 2003 (as far as I know). Still it's a great list. A copy can be found [here](http://gurge.com/amd/top100/).